# Error handling when excel process is closed externally

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing a program that interacts with excel. I have a bit of an issue with regards to closing my application when excel has been killed via task manager.

when my program starts up, it sets `Excel.Application ObjApp = new Excel.Application();`

when it closes, it ends this with

```
if (ObjApp != null)
{
    ObjApp = null;
}
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
ObjApp.Quit();

Environment.Exit(0);
```

However, if excel is killed off via task manager and I exit, I get this

> "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code" at `ObjApp.Quit();`

Essentially what i need to figure out is how to say

> "If ObjApp (My instance of Excel) is still available, Quit it, Else dont."
>   How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be worrying about something you can not control. Wether the user decides to terminate the *Excel* application your program is using or not is not something you should be trying to figure out (there is no safe way to determine if that is the case or not, you can always end up with a race condition, but let's not get sidetracked).

Then what should you do? Implement code that takes care of any reasonable failure scenario your application can handle. What exactly is the cause of the failure is not relevant, it can be anything: it could be a user closing the application, but it could also be some obscure *Excel* bug crashing the app, a *OS* hiccup, a hardware failure, what have you.

And how do you do that? Well, use [exception handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx):

```
try
{
     //Normal code path goes here. Assume appObj is running;
     ObjApp.Quit();
}
//optional catch clauses here
finally
{
    //Safe clean up you want running in normal execution or any managable
    //scenario. By safe I mean you shouldn't be handling/saving/modifying
    //any sensitive data, you should just clean up your COM objects.
    //Anything potentially unsafe should be handled in specific catch
    //clauses where you know the nature of the exception and you can take
    //specific measures to recover or shut down safely.

    //In some unrecoverable scenarios this might not even run.
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ObjApp);
}
```

You can add `catch` clauses for specific exception types for login purposes or to inform the user that something unexpected has happened; `COMException` comes to mind as a good choice, any other exception should probably be passed up the call stack and let someone else who knows better handle it.

Comment: Actually just finished looking into this, just learned i can have more than one catch in my code to cover multiple exceptions. i have included a NullReferenceexception and a COMException catch, which will continue the shutdown code excluding the ObjApp.Quit(); portion. Seems to be working great now.

Comment: @DDuffy Glad to help! About your comment, a `NullReferenceException` is, as Mr. Eric Lippert would call it, a [boneheaded](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) exception. There is no reason you should be handling this excpetion at all, it is a bug in your implementation not an *exceptional * code path your application might take.

Comment: I think the NullReferenceException was being thrown as i was trying to quit ObjApp after i "Nulled" it, as user "blogprogramisty.net" pointed out. I could probably do without that catch.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

`GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` will run destructors for `objects`.

For Your example when `ObjApp == null` then GC may dectruct the object `ObjApp`. and then `ObjApp` will by null.

`ObjApp.Quit()` must by call befeore `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

**Second** You set the `ObjApp` to `null` value and after that You call `ObjApp.Quit()`. If the `Quit()` method is non static then program throw `NullReferenceException` and is expected.

Try this:

```
ObjApp.Quit();

if (ObjApp != null)
{
    ObjApp = null;
}
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Environment.Exit(0);
```

Personaly when I close Excel file i do this:

```
            ...//

            this.workbook.Close();
            this.application.Workbooks.Close();
            this.application.Quit();
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(this.autoFitRange);
            GC.Collect();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(this.numberFormatRange);
            GC.Collect();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(this.range);
            GC.Collect();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(this.workbook);
            GC.Collect();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(this.sheet);
            GC.Collect();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(this.workbooks);
            GC.Collect();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(this.application);
            GC.Collect();
```

As You can see I run `ReleaseComObject` for all object I create during using `COM` excel libary. If I do that I sucess close Excel and the process will disappear form task manager.

May this helps You.

Comment: still getting an error on ObjApp.Quit();, this time its "COMException was unhandled by user code".

Comment: Ok, but now  the problem in other place. ObjApp.Quit() is nessesery?

Comment: As far as i know. Im still a bit of a noob with CSharp, learning as i go. Objapp is my instance of excel, i believe i need to quit that instance when exiting my program in order to clean up properly.

Comment: I add my solusion for this

Comment: Thank you, i used to call the marshal on everything, cant remember why i stopped. However, this wouldnt really solve the issue as the Quit() comes before these, and this is what is throwing the errors at me. Essentially what i need to figure out is how to say "If ObjApp (My instance of Excel) is still available, Quit it, Else dont."

Comment: I think good choice will by open excel do somethink and close excel. When You need to do somthing else dothe same. Open, do staff and close.

Comment: would that not just throw the same error, but in a different place?

Comment: Quite a few things wrong here. First: Why call `GC.Collect` so many times? It's senseless and useless and probably a disaster performance wise. Let the `GC` do it's thing, it's far better at it than you are. If you insist on calling `Collect` (not sure why you'd do this) then by all means, do it once when you've released all your COM objects.

Comment: Second: *"For Your example when `ObjApp == null` then `GC` may dectruct the object `ObjApp`. and then `ObjApp` will by `null`."*. This is false. `ObjApp` is a COM object, its not a managed object, it will never be collected or destroyed by the `GC`. If that were true, then `Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject` would be senseless.

Comment: Third Quoting the same text: *"For Your example when ObjApp == null then GC may dectruct the object ObjApp. **and then** ObjApp will by null."*. Maybe it's a language issue but you seem to be conveying a sequence that is completely false which is: I set and object reference to `null` -> it is a candidate for collection -> it is collected bt the GC -> reference is `null`. Nooo! The reference is `null` the moment you set it to `null`. The referenced object will be collected *when* the `GC` decides to (it might be never in your application's lifetime).

Comment: Fourth: *"Your example when ObjApp == null then **GC may dectruct** the object ObjApp. and then ObjApp will by null."*. Not exactly; when no live references are left, the object is eligible for *collection*. If and when that happens is undetermined and up to the `GC`. Once it *is* collected then it's finalizer (if it has one) is scheduled to run and, again, it might never run.